# Facebook share count for changed URL

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-fql

We often change URL of articles on the site, and then the old URL returns 301 redirect to the new URL.

During a limited time we can still retrieve share count for the old URL (using FQL) and it continues to grow (I think because of re-shares). But after the page is re-scraped Facebook "realises" that both URLs point to the same page and the old share count is lost, both URLs return the same count:

http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url%2C+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+normalized_url+in+%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymail.co.uk%2Fnews%2Farticle-3657160%2FBritain-brink-EU-referendum-result-knife-edge-Leave-scores-HUGE-victory-Sunderland-outperforms-predictions-Swansea-Remain-pins-hopes-London.html%27%2C%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymail.co.uk%2Fnews%2Farticle-3657160%2FDavid-Cameron-QUITS-Prime-Minister-voters-Brexit-EU-referendum.html%27%29

There are several questions:

1. Is there any way to "assign" share count of the old URL to the new URL?
2. Is there any way to retrieve old share count?
3. Maybe, there is a way to instruct Facebook to never re-scrape a particular URL so it can always have old share count available?
4. Would re-shares of old URL be added to share count of new URL (after the page is re-scraped and facebook links two objects)?

Comment: Your only sensible option is to keep the original URLs reachable, so that the scraper can still request the OG meta data from them. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144 That is the only way to not “split” the overall number of likes and shares across different URLs.

Comment: That's not a viable option unfortunately, the old URL should redirect to the new one...

Comment: You can redirect normal human visitors, and implement an exception for the FB scraper (can be recognized by its User-Agent, see further down on same documentation page.)

Comment: I guess that's what we may do...